# Rails separate app or engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have an app and I would like to build an admin management system for it that would be using the same database and probably even models. I want to keep it separate from an app but because I want to use share models between the two, I'm debating wether to use an engine or build a separate app?

One reason I'm more inclined towards a separate app is because I can deploy it separately without affecting the main app.

Any suggestions, opinions or experience?

Thanks!

Comment: I always use engines, but is it really meaningful for you... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend engines. Spree E-commerce is a very good example of separating a single app into engines representing core, frontend and backend. And it is very clear and handy in support.

https://github.com/spree/spree

Comment: Would it be possible to deploy an engine independently of the main app ? I will have it in a separate repo.  And I usually use capistrano for deploying.

Comment: You'll need some dummy app that mounts the engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Oleg.  But just to make sure I understand correctly, you're suggesting to create separate dummy app that mounts an engine from my main/container app?

Comment: It depends on your architecture. A management system usually consists of some core and functional modules. The core can be the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would place the shared models, migrations & code in an engine and use it in two applications: the admin app and the normal app.  You might find these useful:

https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators

http://pivotallabs.com/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines/